# Read both header and body in one call using java

Tags: download, jakarta-mail

I have a mail reader class which sets the FetchProfile and later does a msg.getContent. 
I want to do both reading of header and content in one call, basically download the full mail in one call. Because I have observed msg.getcontent makes a call to the server to get the body/content , if we can download the full mail in one call, a call to the server can be saved.

Is this possible?

The code is similar to this

```
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    /* Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox */
    Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(
            new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));

    /* Use a suitable FetchProfile */
    FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
    fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
    fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
    inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
        Message message = messages[i];

        **String content = message.getContent();**
        System.out.println("Content : " + content);
    }
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks and Regards
Raaghu.K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the **entire** message in one call, and don't need to use any of the features of the IMAP protocol, you have two choices:

1. Use POP3 instead of IMAP.
2. Use the Message.writeTo method to write the message content to a file or byte array and process it from there, e.g., using the MimeMessage constructor that takes an InputStream.  (This makes a local copy of the entire message.)

Comment: Yes. This method works, but little dangerous to implement as it can download the full mail (attachment too) and might cause Out of memory.

Comment: Yup, but that's what you asked for, "download the full mail in one call".  There's no way to download the headers and just the main body of the message in one call because until you examine the structure of the message you don't know where the main body of the message is.

Comment: Right. Your approach and suggestions answers my question, I have just explained the danger/draw back